# Rails Facebook avatar to data-uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to pull a facebook avatar via auth. Here's what i'm doing:

```
def image_uri
  require 'net/http'
  image = URI.parse(params[:image]) # https://graph.facebook.com/565515262/picture
  fetch = Net::HTTP.get_response(image)
  based = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' << Base64.encode64(fetch)
  render :text => based
end
```

I'm getting the following error (new error — edited):

```
Connection reset by peer
```

I've tried googling about, I can't seem to get a solution, any ideas?

**I'm basically looking for the exact functioning of PHP's `file_get_contents()`**

Comment: params[:image] is obviously not what you think, that's the only reason for receiving that exception, because the string does not look like a URI

Comment: I don't know RoR well, but your URI: https://graph.facebook.com/565515262/picture results in a 301 redirect to a new URI. Is your function able to deal with this?

Comment: @cpilko It worked fine in PHP using file_get_contents, i'm basically looking for that exact functioning.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping the URI before parsing:

`URI.parse URI.escape(params[:image])`

Make sure that `params[:image]` does contain the uri you want to parse... I would instead pass the userid and interpolate it into the uri.

`URI.parse URI.escape("https://graph.facebook.com/#{params[:image]}/picture)"`

Comment: Using your first suggestion, I get the following error: `undefined method 'gsub' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: `params[:image]` is nil. Where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 0):

1. Does it throw the same error when you use a static string "https://graph.facebook.com/565515262/picture"
2. What does it say when you do

   ```
   render :text => params[:image]
   ```
3. If both of the above don't answer your question then please try specifying the use of HTTPS-

   ```
   uri = URI('https://secure.example.com/some_path?query=string')
   Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https').start do |http|
       request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
       response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
   end
   ```

Presuming you are on ruby < 1.9.3, you will also have to

```
require 'net/https'
```

If you are on ruby 1.9.3 you don't have to do anything.

**Edit**

If you are on the latest version, you can simply do:

```
open(params[:image]) # http://graph.facebook.com/#{@user.facebook_id}/picture
```

Comment: My mistake, I was testing using the wrong get param in the url. 1. Ok the current error is this: `Connection reset by peer` 2. `https://graph.facebook.com/565515262/picture` (i'm on 1.9.3)

Comment: The connection reset by peer error is being thrown because you are trying to access an https resource via http.

Comment: The open method returns this error: `No such file or directory - https://graph.facebook.com/565515262/picture`

Comment: What happens when you set the uri scheme as https?

Comment: Yea, sorry Open is for a file stream from an actual file, not a web resource. But it does the same thing as php's get_file_contents (only for local files :P) Did you figure this out yet?